# Spring Tool Suite Project import issues

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I imported existing Maven projects into my spring-tool-suite "eclipse" IDE but the projects folders doesn't show up in my workspace directory.

What might be the problem?

PS: For instance if you import a normal Java project into Eclipse IDE you get the option of checking a box to copy the project into the workspace, but in spring-tool-suite there is no such option.

Comment: I think maven import don't offer copying projects into workspace and hence you workspace folder doesn't have them.

Comment: additional comment: choose the "import existing Maven projects" from the import dialog.